# Nested loops for array items

Tags: javascript

I have 3 different Arrays(ArrayA, ArrayB, ArrayC) which I am iterating through the value of each array items line by line.

ArrayA has 20 items in it,

ArrayB has 10 items in it

ArrayC has 8 items in it.

When I iterate through each item of ArrayA to get the value of the Array, I want to use each items of the Array(ArrayA, ArrayB, ArrayC) with one another without repeating the operation for each item of the ArrayB and ArrayC.

This challenge makes me to resort to nested for loop so that I can iterate through the items of each Array but the problem is that the inner loop get executed all at once before the outer loop which is not what I want.

My code:

```
arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

arrayB = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

arrayC = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];


for (var i = 0; i == arrayA.length; i++) {
  console.log(arrayA[i]);

  for (var j = 1; j <= arrayB.length; j++) {
    /*I want to pick the current value of this arrayB because I will use it with arrayA current value but I don't want all the items of this current arrayB values but the for loop will finish the iteration first*/
    console.log(arrayB[j]);

    for (var k = 1; k <= arrayC.length; k++) {
      /*I want to pick the current value of this arrayC because I will use it with arrayA and arrayB current value but I don't want all the items of this arrayC values but the for loop will finish the iteration first*/
      console.log(arrayC[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is that when I pick one item in  arrayA, one item in arrayB and one item in arrayC and use them and iterate again from arrayA and pick the next item, to arrayB and pick the next item and to arrayC and pick the next item and do the same. The problem is that the inner loop finishes the iteration before going back to the outer loop and also because arrayB and arrayC have lesser items compare to arrayA items, their iteration finish before arrayA, once the arrayB and arrayC finish their items they should automatically start from begining of the array until arrayA finishes its own iteration.

Comment: `[I]` should be `[i]`. JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you show sample inputs and desired results?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but it sounds like you just want *one* loop over ArrayA.  And in that loop you'd use that index value on all three arrays, with some added logic to account for when ArrayB and ArrayC are smaller than ArrayA.  (e.g. using a modulo/remainder operator with the index value.)  Can you clarify?

Comment: 1) don't use nested arrays  2) set your `for` based on how you want it to work, it *looks* like to `arrayA.length` 3) reference A/B/C as `arrayA[i % arrayA.length]` etc rather than just `array[i]` - this will cover "*once the arrayB and arrayC finish their items they should automatically start from begining of the array*"

Comment: it looks like you want to get the cartesian product.. please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript).

Comment: @barmar, the question is that I am iterating through the 3 arrays which are arrayA, arrayB and arrayC and I want to pick the item of each array and use them once until I iterate through all the arrays and when arrays(arrayA and arrayB) with few items finish iteration they should restart until the array with highest array(arrayA) finish iteration.

Comment: @AiimmaGlobal, please add an example with three items for every array and add the result of of this data.

Comment: To iterate through item of array you use either for, foreach, for in arrayA loop etc... I will iterate through each array to get the value and the iteration would finish at once but I don't want the iteration of arrayB and arrayC to iterate through all the items before going to pick from arrayA, I want to be picking each item from each array until I finish the iteration and any array that finishes first should restart again until other array(which is arrayA) finish its own iteration.

Comment: @Nina Scholz I have edited the code in the question and I have added a sample array value items.

Comment: Your restatement is not any clearer. Sample desired results would be incredibly helpful. If they would be too large, try using smaller inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the largest array using a single for loop and use the modulo operator to index the smaller arrays. Here is the most Python like way to implement this in JavaScript.

```js
const arrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const arrayB = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const arrayC = [1, 2, 3];

for (let [index, value] of arrayA.entries()) {
  console.log(value, arrayB[index % arrayB.length], arrayC[index % arrayC.length]);
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 1
5 5 2
6 6 3
7 1 1
8 2 2
9 3 3
```

Comment: Bad guy , I respect you

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the longest array and take an adjusted index for smaller arrays.

```js
const
    a = [1, 2],
    b = [3, 4, 5],
    c = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
    
for (let i = 0, l = Math.max(a.length, b.length, c.length); i < l; i++) {
    console.log(a[i % a.length], b[i % b.length], c[i % c.length]);
}
```

Comment: With this array

const
    c = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    b = [3, 4, 5],
    a = [1, 2];

The expected output should be:

6,3,1
7,4,2
8,5,1
9,3,2
0,4,1

The logic is it picks the item of the array with the highest items(c) with arrays(b,a) of lower items until the arrays(b,a) with lower items finish their iteration and they start again. it picks the array with highest items once and use with the next item of the arrays with lower items(b,a)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, I think this is what you want:

```js
var arrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
var arrayB = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var arrayC = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
  console.log("ArrayA:", arrayA[i]);

  for (var j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
    console.log("ArrayB:", arrayB[j]);

    for (var k = 0; k < arrayC.length; k++) {
      console.log("ArrayC:", arrayC[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if I am mistaken.

> The code snippet might not show the complete console logs, so please copy it into your code editor or try it in your browser's console.